# The format of class data loaded in method area of jvm by the class loader?

Tags: jvm, classloader

What is the format of the class related information loaded in method area by the class loader of jvm? Does the class information loaded in method area by class loader is present in machine language(native instructions set)?

Actually as the JVM's execution engine converts the bytecode into native instructions set. So I wanted to know does the class related information loaded by classloaders in method area of jvm is already present in native instructions set or present in any other format and later gets converted to native instructions set by JVM's execution engine.

Comment: When loading a class, JVM gets input in the specified [class file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se18/html/jvms-4.html) and parses it into the internal representation. There is no more "format" at this point - class metadata resides in memory in implementation-specific structures. Not sure what you mean by "machine language". Why do you ask?

Comment: @apangin the "implementation-specific structures" is it in the form of 0s and 1s i.e in machine language? Actually I wanted to know is the class metadata is already present in 0s and 1s form in jvm method area and doesn't get further converted to the final machine language output (native instructions set) by the jvm?

Comment: A class file contains a data structure. Executable code only makes a small part of it. When all you want to know, is whether bytecode instructions are immediately converted to native instructions, the answer is, that’s implementation specific and usually, they are not.